# addition of rules and value assigning in an ontology

Tags: conditional-statements, ontology, rules, swrl

Say a degree recommendation ontology which is supposed to recommend a degree programme according to certain set of results you get for an exam.

E.g. a students chooses a stream he did the exam in and his results are: for chemistry, physics, and maths are C, C, C. Thereby he is supposed to be recommended a degree from a particular university.

The class hierarchy of the ontology is as

```
stream
  subject                                                                              
University
  Faculty
    Department
      Degree
```

Object properties have been defined as well.

1. Should the universities such as "University A" , "University B" have properties assigned in the class or to the individual?
2. How would I be able to assign different results to each subject?
3. How would I be able to add rules and conditions to the ontology?

E.g. engineering stream consists of only 3 subjects that can be done which are chemistry, physics and maths.
E.g. if you get a result of 'F' in one of those subjects a degree wont be recommended.

Comment: I'm not convinced with what you call the class hierarchy. Why would `Faculty` be a subclass of `University`? Or `Degree` be a subclass of `Department`? For me, those are totally different semantic relations, but clearly not "subclass of" - but that's just my opinion.

Comment: 1. given that the universities are obviously instances of the class `University`, the properties should be assigned to the instances, not the class.

Comment: 2. not sure what you mean, but in OWL this would most likely take an intermediate object as you have an n-ary relation: `studentA hasResult result1 . result1 hasSubject Chemistry . result1 grade F` - that's how OWL works, the are only binary relations, thus there is no other way (I'll omit reification for obvious reasons here)

Comment: 3. not sure what you mean, just add SWRL rules. But keep in mind: in OWL there is a) the Open World Assumption and b) no Unique Names Assumption. This will affect your plans for sure